# Why does my lambda function gives me message internal server error instead of proper error response?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, typescript, aws-lambda

I have written a very simple lambda function which should give an error Message as a response [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-mode-exceptions.html)

**My Lambda Function**

```
export const throwSomeError: Handler = async (event: APIGatewayEvent, context: Context) => {
  throw new Error( 'Something Went Wrong');
}
```

I was expecting response like below:

**Expected Response**

```
 {
  "errorMessage": "Something went Wrong",
  "errorType": "Error",
  "stackTrace": [
    "exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:10:17)"
  ]
}
```

**Response I am getting**

```
{"message": "Internal server error"}
```

You can see it [here](https://23hdf8cvt3.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/hello/error)

I am very new to aws-lambda. I am using `typescript` and `serverless framework`. I don't think it should be an issue. Please someone can figure out what is wrong in here?

Comment: Something else failed?

Comment: Do you know how get to your Cloudwatch logs?

Comment: @AluanHaddad I don't think so.

Comment: @stwilz Yeah I will update the post after seeing the logs.

Comment: I found that the response I was expecting is something that is saved as logs in cloudwatch and is not sent in the response. Thanks everyone for help.